# Translate 2D data onto a 3D surface

Tags: python, 3d, 2d, mayavi, uv-mapping

I might have an unusual question so please bear with me.  I am working with a dataset which represents x,y coordinates and at each coordinate there is a value, let's call this the activation value.  Now my task is to translate this activation value onto the surface of a 3D model.  I already have a 3D model, which consist of three matrices (each matrix contains the 3D points of the model, for example one matrix would have the x coordinate values, while another would have the y coordinate and the last one would have the z coordinate).  I want to know is there a way to apply my 2D information and apply this the surface of the 3D model and if so what would be the best method?

I should mention that I am programming using python and my 3D rendering is done with mayavi.

Comment: Okay i have heard of UV mapping but is it possible to do this in mayavi.  And if so do you have an example